# How do you use Async Web Service to perform authentication?

Tags: wcf, web-services, silverlight-4.0, asynchronous

I am new to Silverlight and need to user a WCF Service (dataService) to authenticate against a database.

I can return the results from the database but, these are in the completed event.  If I use a property and the OnPropertyChanged event to bind to my login then I may run into the
situation where the code sees the property before it's set.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What property do you mean? Is it the property for the login Id ?

Comment: if I set a property in the LoginViewModel for my LoginDialog then I'm afraid it won't set the property in time to do the authentication.  My LoginDialog is a child window as well.  Is it possible to bind data to a child window and use the binding to also dismiss the child window?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure and wait for the property to be set, then do your authentication afterward.

One way to do this would be to an attached property to your bound value, gave the attached property update the source on each keystroke.

Comment: So I would close my child window(Login dialog) and then do authentication?

Comment: that would be one posssible way of handling that.